# IOS: error in app purchase

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I use in my app a section with app purchse but when I test it I have a problem and this is my result in console:

```
response for request product data
2011-09-26 19:14:37.601 MyApp[1233:707] Feature: puzzle, Cost: 0.790000, ID: com.mycompany.MyApp.puzzle
2011-09-26 19:14:44.973 MyApp[1233:707] Review request cannot be checked now: (null)
2011-09-26 19:14:44.980 MyApp[1233:707] making paymentQueue updatedTransactions
2011-09-26 19:14:46.095 MyApp[1233:707] making paymentQueue updatedTransactions
2011-09-26 19:14:46.098 MyApp[1233:707] FAILED!!! 4B2D3ECB-784D-415E-B3EA-942D88BD5A23
```

practically when I start my app and push on in app purchase button I have an alert with "Impossible to connect to apple store" and this result in console.
What's the problem?

the code where I have the problem is:

```
- (void) buyFeature:(NSString*) featureId
     onComplete:(void (^)(NSString*)) completionBlock         
    onCancelled:(void (^)(void)) cancelBlock
{
self.onTransactionCompleted = completionBlock;
self.onTransactionCancelled = cancelBlock;

[MKSKProduct verifyProductForReviewAccess:featureId                                                              
                               onComplete:^(NSNumber * isAllowed)
 {
     if([isAllowed boolValue])
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Review request approved", @"")
                                                         message:NSLocalizedString(@"You can use this feature for reviewing the app.", @"")
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", @"")
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         [alert release];

         if(self.onTransactionCompleted)
             self.onTransactionCompleted(featureId);                                         
     }
     else
     {
         [self addToQueue:featureId];
     }

 }                                                                   
                                  onError:^(NSError* error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Review request cannot be checked now: %@", [error description]);
     [self addToQueue:featureId];
 }];    
}
```

Comment: Post the error you get from storekit, e.g. localizedDescription.

Comment: I think this log is printed by your code. So post it...

Comment: Still not displaying a StoreKit error.  Also, is '4B2D3ECB-784D-415E-B3EA-942D88BD5A23' the UDID of the device?  If so, that's a simulator UDID, StoreKit shouldn't function for the simulator.

Comment: ah noooo ok I understand my problem, the featureID is not equal to bundle id of application, I solved it